# Marklogic and Geoserver integration not working

Tags: geoserver, marklogic-8

We have successfully generated the jar and placed in the Geoserver lib folder, but could see the below exception.

https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-geotools-plugin/

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory$SecurityContext
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
>           ... 154 more

Comment: That class is in the MarkLogic Client API, which is a dependency for the project: https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-geotools-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle#L36  Have you verified that all of the jars for the dependencies are also in the Geoserver lib folder?

Comment: when we build the jar, could see the below 2 jars and placed these in geoserver lib. And what other jars?. Could you please share any doc if you have.
marklogic-geotools-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT
jacocoagent